# Is it wrong to expand a question out to a larger scope?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just posted an answer to this question:

[What is causing motion sickness when using the Rift?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150377/what-is-causing-motion-sickness-when-using-the-rift)

And, it is a good question, but I think it's limited in its scope.  Because, the phenomenon being described is not just present when using Occulus Rift.  But, really, any game with a 3-dimensional component.  FPSs, 3-D rendered effects, etc. etc.

I want to change the question by making it:

*What causes motion sickness when playing video games (and especially the Occulus Rift)?*

I think the original poster's question should stand, with perhaps an extra line in the body to expand the scope.  But, I think it's a great question that affects a lot of gamers, not just the few who use an Occulus Rift.

Would this be modifying the question too much, even though the purpose of doing so is altruistic?

Comment: In general, sure, it's okay sometimes. In the specific case you cited? No way. You're very fundamentally changing the question here.

Comment: So, if I were to post the generalized question alone, wouldn't people tag it as a possible duplicate?  If you read my answer you will see that it's not a feature of OR that is causing this to happen.

Comment: OK, I've taken my lumps.  Question withdrawn.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's actually too wide; the new Oculus Rift revealed at CES should have less issues due to technology changes.

Yes, the answer depends on the technologies being used, but the technologies being used depend on the specific product.

Comment: I would argue that the question was "What causes the motion sickness?"  Not, "Does OR cause it?"  Therefore, it is far less technology specific.

Comment: I agree. Even expanding the question to all VR headsets, I think would be too broad, so it follows that all causes of motion sickness, VR headset or not, would be too broad.

Comment: @MBraedley The underlying cause is the human being, not the headset.  The answer is always the same regardless of the hardware because the human component doesn't change.  It would be true that each company attempts to combat this effect differently, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @DavidM you've stated that you're prone to motion sickness, so maybe there's some bias entering in here. From a quick look over the question, it could be as simple as the headset not being properly adjusted (both positionally and optically) that caused the motion sickness. That's hardware dependent.  There's other things specific to VR units that don't apply to FPS games played on a monitor. There is a human component, but many gamers who are fine playing on a monitor will still get motion sickness with a VR headset, because it's a VR headset. It's inherent to the technology, not the person.

Comment: @MBraedley I am actually not prone to ANY other sort of motion sickness.  Just from gaming.  And, it's a matter of degree of input.  But, the fact remains that even if it can be adjusted, or fixed, or otherwise, the underlying cause is still a vestibular-occular discrepancy.